# Firebase Simultaneous connections in spark plan

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If Firebase Simultaneous connections in spark plan is more than 100 will my app work? i want to just read data from firebase not write, will my app work if offline capablities is enabled in my app and simultaneous connections more than 100.

and can i buy flame plan just for one month ?

Answer (score 0):

Once your database reaches its maximum number of concurrent connections, the database stops accepting new connections. Users that are already connected will continue to work. Once a user disconnects from the database, it will allow a new user in.

All plans are on a month-to-month basis. You can indeed upgrade to Flame for a single month, and downgrade again the next month.

Comment: will it work if i enable offline capablities ?i just want to read data not write.